# Getting rid of port in URL for django installation in production

Tags: django, nginx, url, port, gunicorn

I'm trying for the first time to deploy my Django application on a server but so far I wasn't able to get rid of port in my URL. Right now I'm using Gunicorn with Nginx with the following configuration.

**Nginx /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.conf**

```
server {
       listen 8000;
       server_name example.com;
       location = /favicon.ico {access_log off;log_not_found off;}

       location /static/ {
         root /home/webapp/um;
       }
       location /media/ {
         root /home/webapp/um;
       }

       location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/home/webapp/um/um.sock;
       }
     }
```

**/etc/nginx/proxy_params**

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

**Gunicorn /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
Description=gunicorn service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/webapp/um/
ExecStart=/root/um/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/webapp/um/um.sock um.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Gunicorn binding**

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 um.wsgi:application
```

Changing port 8000 with port 80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.conf gives me a 404 on nginx. Using  port 8000 I'm able to see the site using http://example.com:8000/myapp but I'm aiming at using http://example.com/myapp as my address.
As a side note, the VPS I'm installing the app on came with Plesk already installed with which I'm also not familiar with. I don't know if Plesk might be interferring in catching traffic from port 80.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Alasdair. Shouldn't Gunicorn use the binding set in /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service? I've included the last binding in the question since it's a command that I've executed, but I don't know if it's interfering. If the cause is the mismatch, what should I do to correct it?

Comment: You're right, I saw your `gunicorn --bind` command and missed the command in command in your service file.

Comment: What do the Nginx logs show if you change from port 8000 to 80 and restart Nginx? Is the 404 coming from Nginx, or from Plesk? If Plesk is listening on port 80 then you wouldn't be able to bind Nginx to it.

Comment: if I change the port to 80, visiting http://example.com/myapp I got a 404 from nginx, while visiting http://example.com/ I see a plesk page that says "If you are seeing this message, the website for beta.urbismap.com is not available at this time.
If you are the owner of this website, one of the following things may be occurring:

You have not put any content on your website.
Your provider has suspended this page.
Please login to https://example.com:8443 to receive instructions on setting up your website."

Comment: BTW you don't want `root /home/webapp/um` for you `/static/` and `/media/` locations. That means that you can view your source code under `/static/ and `/media/`.

Comment: If the traffic is going Plesk -> Nginx, how is that configured? The path might be rewritten, so Nginx isn't seeing a request for `/myapp/` any more. The access/error logs might show you what's going on.

Comment: the error log for nginx shows `[ N 2020-04-28 03:24:04.2719 31423/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1296 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2020-04-28 03:24:04.3079 31580/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1307 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2020-04-28 03:24:04.3177 31583/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1311 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2020-04-28 03:24:04.3178 31583/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2020-04-28 03:24:04.3382 31583/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:986 ]: Passenger core online, PID 31583`

Comment: on the access log nothing useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of struggling, I found the solution. Turns out my config was correct, but there was an nginx config file automatically written by plesk that was catching requests on port 80. The content of such file is

```
server {
    listen 111.111.111.111:80;

    location ^~ /plesk-site-preview/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8880;
            proxy_set_header Host             plesk-site-preview.local;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_cookie_domain plesk-site-preview.local $host;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://111.111.111.111:7080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
    listen 111.111.111.111:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/certWpPLaPv;
    ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/certWpPLaPv;

    location ^~ /plesk-site-preview/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8880;
            proxy_set_header Host             plesk-site-preview.local;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_cookie_domain plesk-site-preview.local $host;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass https://111.111.111.111:7081;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Once I removed that file from inclusion in nginx.conf everything started working. As a suggestion for whoever is facing a similar situation, I would recommend to check what Nginx is processing using the following command

```
nginx -T
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You just need to listen this server on port 80 instead of 8000
   save gunicorn as described

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name 52.14.64.58 example.com www.example.com;
       location = /favicon.ico {access_log off;log_not_found off;}

       location /static/ {
         root /home/webapp/um;
       }
       location /media/ {
         root /home/webapp/um;
       }

       location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/home/webapp/um/um.sock;
       }
     }
```

52.14.64.58 => is ipv4 of your virtual machine, it could be anything in your case.

2. Now time to make changes in our django settings

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['IP_ADDRESS', 'example.com', 'www.example.com']
```

3. Now check nginx status then restart gunicorn and nginx . I hope it would work for you.

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

4. Now setup your domain by it's dns settings.

Comment: Tried that, but Plesk courtesy page keeps on showing

Comment: can you share your django urls file here